# Approximation of Periodic Parabolic Function by Fourier Series!

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, fourier, fourier-series, taylor-expansion

I've just tried to approximate the periodic-parabolic signal by Fourier Series. I know, this sounds a bit strange. I am just trying to figure out relationship between Fourier Series and Taylor Expansion.

First of all, I generated parabolic pulse train and its period $2\pi$. On the other hand, time duration of parabolic pulse train  is $10\pi$. After that, I've just tried to approximate this signal by Fourier Series. Here is my simple code on Matlab.

```
  TimeRes=1/(2*pi);  % Time Resolution 
  t1=0:TimeRes:2*pi-TimeRes; % One Period 
  SinglePeriodVector = zeros(1,length(t1)); 
  SinglePeriodVector = t1.*(2*pi-t1);
  Signal = repmat(SinglePeriodVector, [1, 5]);
  t2=0:TimeRes:5*(2*pi-TimeRes)+TimeRes;
  t2=[t2 t2(end)];

 %% Fourier Series Approximation for Even Signals 
 a0=(2/3)*pi^2;
 FS=zeros(size(t2));
 N=1;

 for n=1:2:N
      FS=a0+FS-4*cos(n*t2/(n^2))
 end
```

After first run, I successfully composed to signal. Here is the result. [image: 2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, one period of your signal is not strictly parabolic. It is made of a piecewise polynomial signal, parabolic on the first half, and on degree 0 on the second one

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show your Fourier series for your repetitive signal *in math*.  If I'm reading your code right, then, first, you have a typo (`1/pi * n` in one spot, `1/n * pi` in another), and second, you don't have the Fourier series for your given curve.

Comment: Maybe you find this example helpful: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/math_for_ms/kap_1/backbone/r_su22.html#x57-560003.11.4

Comment: I edited the signal type @Laurent Duval

Comment: I followed the link you suggest. And obtained  at first run. You can see the result. Thanks @JuhaP

Comment: I edited and showed my correct result @TimWescott Thanks